# Table of contents in multicol alignment problem

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, multicol

In my report I'd like to have a short table of contents, thus I printed it with multicol in two columns to safe space. But the alignment on the top is like in the picture.[image]

I'd more prefer it if the first row of the second column is aligned to the first entry of my toc of the first column. All in all Section 3 should move to the left column below Section 2 and Section 4 shall stay in one line with Section 1.

I found some solutions, but they were somehow very manual where you have to write yourself which section appears in which column. Here, so far, everything happens automatically :)

My code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%% additional packages
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%%%%

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %set depth of printed table of contets.

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
  {}{}
\makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}


\section{Introduction}%%%%%%%%%%Introduction
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Approach}%%%%%%%%%%Approach
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Experimental results}%%%%%%%%%%Experimental results
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Discussion}%%%%%%%%%%Discussion
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Summary}%%%%%%%%%%Summary
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}


\end{document}
```

Thank you very much,
SemtexB

Comment: Could you fix your code so that it (1) compiles, and (2) produces the output you show in the image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%% additional packages
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}
%%%%%%

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %set depth of printed table of contets.

\makeatletter


\patchcmd{\l@section}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
  {}{}

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \end{multicols}%
    }

\makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents


\section{zz}
aa
\section{bbbb}
\subsection{xgxgxgxg}
aaa
\subsection{xgxgxgxg}
aaa
\subsection{xgxgxgxg}
aaa
\subsection{xgxgxgxg}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, also with other tocdepth's. Thank you!

Comment: A little addition: The `\multicolsep` length sets the space before the `multicols` environment. By default this behavior diminishes the space between the section title (`\contentsname`) and the TOC, which looks odd in comparison with the rest of the sections in the document. To keep some consistency, add:
`\setlength{\multicolsep}{2\multicolsep}`. (There might be better solutions/explanations, though.)

Answer (score 5):

A shorter, if sneakier, solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{fee}
\subsection{foo}
\subsection{bar}
\section{fie}
\section{fo}
\section{fum}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but i had the same problem and found a solution that i judge simpler, so... just remove the table of contents title, add it manually before \tableofcontents. Your code would then look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%% additional packages
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%%%%

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %set depth of printed table of contets.

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
  {}{}
\makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.

\begin{document}

\section*{Contents} % As suggested by TeXnician
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}


\section{Introduction}%%%%%%%%%%Introduction
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Approach}%%%%%%%%%%Approach
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Experimental results}%%%%%%%%%%Experimental results
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Discussion}%%%%%%%%%%Discussion
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}

\section{Summary}%%%%%%%%%%Summary
\subsection{bla}
\subsubsection{blabla}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not a good idea. Maybe you could do a `\section*{Contents}` instead to avoid manual formatting. Otherwise it is fine of course.

Comment: You're right, thats much better, thanks.